# Jenkins adding additional . to tagging

Tags: jenkins

I have a sample jenkins script which I am using to build my image

```
pipeline {
    environment{
        registry = "leexha/sampleadd"
        registyCredential = 'dockerhub'
        dockerImage = ''
    }

    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Git clone'){
            steps{
                git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/leeadh/terraform_simpleapp.git'
            }

        }

        stage ('Building image'){
            steps{
                script{
                    dockerImage = docker.build(registry + ":development .","--build-arg endpoint_arg='http://22222:8200' --build-arg token_arg='s.aaaaa'")

                }
            }

        }


        stage ('Pushing to Docker Hub'){
            steps{
                script{
                    println dockerImage.id
                    docker.withRegistry('',registyCredential){

                        dockerImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

the build is successful. However when I println the dockerImage under the stage ('Pushing to Docker Hub') i notice it states that

```
leexha/sampleadd:development .
```

As a result tagging fails and it cant push. Im wondering why it puts an additional . at the end of the image when I did not put it anywhere.

in line

```
 dockerImage = docker.build(registry + ":development .","--build-arg endpoint_arg='http://22222:8200' --build-arg token_arg='s.aaaaa'")
```

if i dont put the . after development, the build will fail.